# Sql Server 2005 Copy Only backup

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a database in Sql Server 2005. The database is configured to be backed up as Full (sunday) and Differential (weeknights) on a mediaset at a particular path.

When I run the command:

```
BACKUP DATABASE COB
TO DISK = ’C:BackupsCOB.bak’ 
WITH COPY_ONLY;
```

to backup the database to a different path, does that break the pre-configured backup sequence. I know that usually people run the copy_only backup without changing the backup sequence, but I was unsure what would happen if I changed the path. Still Learning. Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a backup `with copy_only`, it does not interfere with the full/differential backup sequence.

You can think of a `with copy_only` backup as *it never happened*.